Could we impose to a SARIMA model that the sum of predict values equals a given value (in R)?
I work on a forecasting R model (SARIMA) with monthly time series data. However, for the last year of my training data (2023), I don't have the details by months but I have the annual value.
I want to predict 2023 data by month thanks to my SARIMA model, by adding a constraint on my model : the sum of my 12 predict months equals my observed annual value.
Do anyone knows a function in R allowing to implement such a constraint in my SARIMA ? I didn't find so far a satisfactory solution with "arima" or "auto.arima" functions.
Thank's a lot. Maxime
